# Incrementing content with extra text after save/publish

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm using one plugin for slicing post to various subposts. And now I want to add to the end of the content one line of the text with page break tag and shortcode on post publish.

But the code I wrote isn't working:

```
add_filter('publish_post', 'increment_content');
function increment_content($content) {
   $content .= '<!--nextpage--> [display-posts category_display=\"true\" image_size=\"thumbnail\" title=\"Suggested Posts\" wrapper=\"div\" wrapper_class=\"suggested\"]';
return $content;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `add_filter('the_content', 'increment_content', 20);`

Your current function should be added as you assume.

Comment: I've tried that but it looks like it's adding the extra content after everything else is added so that plugin I'm using doesn't render it as part of the content. I wanted to add the text to the db together with the rest of post on publish not when the_content is called.

Comment: Then your question should be "Save content with extra text." right?

Comment: Yes i guess :) Sorry If i wasn't clear enough